# Collision between piston inside face and an atom at an certain angle is energy dissipation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, collision

My question refers to a certain scenario. Let us assume that we have an cylindre-piston assembly with an ideal gas in it and we compress the gas, do work on it. Work in classical mechanics is defined as the dot product between force and change in distance.
If we now collide during the compression with an particle which "meets" the inside face of the piston at an angle then, in my opinion, only one force component for example Fx contributes to an work transfer and the other doesnt, right. That would mean the other force component Fy is kind of dissipated.

Answer (score 0):

If each collision was like a billiard ball, with the angle of incidence equal to the angle of reflexion, only the $x$ component would be affected by a moving piston.

But there is no reason to model the molecules bouncing to the cylinder and piston surfaces like that.

They are just scattered in a random direction, and its velocity module increases due to the velocity of a compressing piston.

Faster molecules means increased temperature and pressure. The later due to greater momentum change at each collision and due to more collision in a given time.